# mat-icon does not center in mat-button

Tags: css, angular

When I make the font bigger the mat-icon is no longer centered. how can I center the icon inside of the button vertically and horizontally? (Note that the class "mat-icon" is built-in so the css  does work specifying the class in the element)

html:

```
<button mat-fab class="add-picture">
    <mat-icon>add_to_photos</mat-icon>
</button>
```

css:

```
.add-picture {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.mat-icon {
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Set display flex, justify content center and align item center for add picture class

Comment: Setting the display to flex already changes the position of the icon. But no matter what I do I cannot get it centered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your css like this

```
.mat-icon {
  font-size: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
// this is the parent span angular inserts for icon inside mat-fab
::ng-deep.mat-fab .mat-button-wrapper {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

You can chek it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-4az4rq?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html